# removing elements from a sequence using for/yield

Tags: scala

Given a `Future[Seq[Widget]]`, where Widget contains a `amount : Int` property, I'd like to return a `Seq[Widget]` but for only those `Widget`s whose amount value is greater than 100.  I believe the `for { if … } yield {  }` construct will give me what I want but am unsure how to filter through the Sequence.  I have:

```
val myWidgetFuture :  Future[Seq[Widget]] = ...

for {
  widgetSeq <- myWidgetFuture
  if (??? amount > 100) <— what to put here?
}  yield {
  widgetSeq
}
```

If there's a clean non-yield way of doing this that will also work for me.

Comment: I think I have it, I was trying to put the if filter in the wrong place (at the bottom of the for { }).  I can apparently do yield { widgetSeq.filter(_.amount > 100) }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't even need `yield`. Use `map`.

```
val myWidgetFuture: Future[Seq[Widget]] = ???

myWidgetFuture map { ws => ws filter (_.amount > 100) }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `for … yield` with an `if` filter, you'll need to use two `for`s:

```
for {
  widgetSeq <- myWidgetFuture
} yield for {
  widget <- widgetSeq
  if widget.amount > 100
} yield widget
```

Comment: That last line should be "yield filteredWidgetSeq" indicating it's finishing out with a seq still instead of just a single widget?

Comment: @GlenMazza no, there's no `val filteredWidgetSeq` in that code. The second `for` finishing with a `Seq` is implied by it taking from a `Seq` and then yielding values from it. `for … yield …` [translates to `map`.](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html)